# "Preview" will not open on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

"Preview" will not open on my MacBook Pro. I am using High Sierra 10.13.6.

When I go to open a PDF or a photo, nothing happens. When I right click the Preview app it says Application Not Responding, but also has a list of all the documents I have recently tried to open.

I have tried restarting my laptop and force quitting Preview.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: In a Finder window press SHIFT COMMAND . (period) to show all files. Open the library folder in your home folder and then Preferences. Look for any preference files that start with "com.apple.preview" and delete them. See if that works. Often it's a damaged preference file that causes symptoms like that.